# How to display a Java List<> in PDF document using itext 5.3.0?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

```
{
  List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  list.add(10);
  list.add(20);
  com.itextpdf.text.List A = new com.itextpdf.text.List(list);document.add(A);
}
```

it is showing error argument in List to match parameter.

Comment: Paste the exact error message.

Comment: it is showing constructor List(List<Integer>) is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no constructor in this class that takes a `java.util.List` as a parameter. Please refer to the [Javadoc](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/List.html).

You may want to work with itext's `List` directly:

```
com.itextpdf.text.List a = new com.itextpdf.text.List();
a.add("10");
a.add("20");
```

If working with an existing `java.util.List` you will have to iterate over the items to add them:

```
com.itextpdf.txt.List a = new com.itextpdf.text.List();
List<Integer> integersList = getListFromDb();
for(Integer item : integersList) {
    a.add(item.toString());
}
```

Comment: this was the sample example, i am actually returning a List from DATA BASE and I want to display that list in the pdf document created using Itext. I dont know how to pass each element of List(returned from DB) to ListItem of itext @maksimov

Comment: I have provided another example in the answer, however this isn't what you were asking.

Comment: how to pass elements from JAVA.util.List to com.util.text.List So that i could display the elements int the table?

Comment: @maksimov you should also handle nulls else the line item.toString() might fail if there was no data in the database. a.add(item == null ? "" : item.toString());

Comment: @anshul if you have a new question, i suggest you to create it separately.

Comment: @MihaiC thanks, in the unlikely scenario the list comes back with nulls from the database, I'm sure OP will use your suggestion. I would personally let the OP learn the basic Java on their own.

Comment: @anshul Please accept the anwer: I am the original developer of iText and I confirm that the answer given here is correct. In the comments, you indicate that you do not understand the answer, but that is not caused by a lack of quality in the answer. Rather, you have a **new** and **different** question that reveals a lack of quality in your Java skills.